# draw diagrams with \xymatrix

Tags: matrices, xy-pic

I'm using \xymatrix to draw a diagram and I need some of the arrows to be 
named with a matrix over it. To draw the matrices over arrows, I'm using the \arrow command but, unfortunately, it puts very large matrices and collapses the diagram. The usual size-changing commands, such as \scriptstyle..., do not work. 
could somebody give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the example code that you're working with, to give an indication of what you're trying to do and what's not working?

Answer (score 4):

The `smallmatrix` environments are the right thing to use here, since they by default are small enough to fit into a line of text. You can use `\begin{smallmatrix}`...`\end{smallmatrix}` in place of `\begin{matrix}`...`\end{matrix}` to get something that's small enough.

Then, if you use the `mathtools` package, you can add delimiters: `psmallmatrix` is like `pmatrix` (a matrix delimited by parentheses, but smaller), `bsmallmatrix` uses brackets like `bmatrix`, and so on.

Here's how this looks with arrows in a commutative diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]^{\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}}
  \ar[d]_{\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & -1\\-1 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}}
& B\ar[d]^{\begin{psmallmatrix}c & 0\\d & e\end{psmallmatrix}} \\
C\ar[r]_{\begin{bsmallmatrix}a & 0\\0 & b\end{bsmallmatrix}} & D
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Arun's solution, this is how it would look like with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \arrow{d}[swap]{\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}} \arrow{r}{\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}} \& B \arrow{d}{\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}} \\
    C \arrow{r}[swap]{\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}} \& D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```